# Remove <p> tags with only <br> in them javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to use javascript to remove HTML elements `<p><br></p>`

```
const blog = document.getElementById('blog');
const postNode = document.createElement('div');
postNode.innerHTML = postNode.innerHTML.replace('<p><br></p>', '');
blog.appendChild(postNode);
```

However, the `replace` doesn't seem to get rid of the strings within the `innerHTML`. I *think* it is because the output is currently

```
<h2>This is a heading two</h2><p>This is a paragraph</p><p><br></p><p>This is a paragraph with a <strong>bold</strong> an <em>italic</em> and an <u>underscored</u> text</p><p><br></p>
```

The problem `<p><br></p>`HTML is connected to other elements and thus not a string or substring in it's own right.

Is there some regex magic that can help me out?

Comment: ˋpostNodeˋis yet an empty ˋ<div>ˋ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through `<p>` tags, and `filter` them by whether the tag has exactly one child, and that child is a `<br>`. Then, `.remove()` each of the `<p>`s which pass that test:

```js
[...postNode.querySelectorAll('p')]
  .filter(p => p.children.length === 1 && p.children[0].tagName === 'BR')
  .forEach(p => p.remove());
console.log(postNode.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="postNode">
  <h2>This is a heading two</h2>
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <p><br></p>
  <p>This is a paragraph with a <strong>bold</strong> an <em>italic</em> and an <u>underscored</u> text</p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! What does the `[...` part of the code mean in this context?

Comment: It turns the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` into an array, allowing you to call `.filter` on it. (NodeLists don't have a `.filter` method, but arrays do)

Comment: Fantastic. What is the term of this operator? Wouldn't mind reading up on it. Thank you for the coherent and comprehensive answer.

Comment: That's spread syntax, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax - it can turn iterables into arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead you can use a class to hide the elements you want to hide with

```css
display: none;
```